# Quand faut-il écrire l'accent grave ou aigu sur le e

Tags: diacritiques

Bonjour,

Suite à une question récente portant sur le mot *cél**è**bre*, je me suis demandé pourquoi ce mot portait un accent grave devant deux consonnes, alors que le mot *sél**e**ction* par exemple n'en a pas.

J'ai fait quelques recherches et tous les sites ne semblent pas d'accords entre eux  :

- https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-110491.php ne couvre pas mon exemple célèbre vs sélection :

> **Pas d'accent sur un e qui précède** une consonne double
> ou **deux consonnes qui ne représentent pas un son unique** :
>
> - pou-bel-le
> - in-té-res-sant
> - es-poir

- https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/articles/le-guide-de-usage-des-accents-en-francais#1 en revanche, la règle 3 couvre mon cas (à l'aide d'une règle qui semble un peu tirée par les cheveux) :

> Règle 3 : on met un accent grave sur un « e » lorsque la deuxième lettre qui le suit est soit un « l » ou un « r ».

D'autre sources (ex : http://uoh.univ-montp3.fr/j_ameliore_ma_maitrise_du_francais/fiches-outils/accents_e/co/accents_sur_e.html) font reposer cela sur le découpage en syllabes, ce qui pour moi ne fait que reporter le problème (Encore faut-il savoir exactement comment découper en syllabes!)

Ma question est la suivante :

- existe-t-il une règle officielle ou d'une source reconnue qui permet de savoir dans quel cas l'accent doit être écrit ou non?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

J'ai trouvé ça :

https://www.orthodidacte.com/videos-francais/e-accentue-ou-non/

> La règle est la suivante. Si le e n’est pas la dernière lettre de la syllabe, alors il ne faut pas d’accent. C’est le cas notamment des e suivis d’une consonne double puisqu’on coupe la syllabe entre les deux consonnes.
> En revanche, si le E est la dernière lettre de la syllabe, il faut un accent.

Si on découpe en sylabes :
cé - lè - bre

(Première fois que je vois cette règle)

PS : Comme vous disiez ça oblige à savoir comment découper en syllabes ...

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse. Du coup, j'aimerais bien savoir pourquoi on découpe *cé-lè-bre et non *cé-leb-re* par exemple ?

Comment: J'ai trouvé ça qui explique pas mal :D 
http://uoh.univ-montp3.fr/j_ameliore_ma_maitrise_du_francais/fiches-outils/accents_e/co/syllabe.html

http://uoh.univ-montp3.fr/j_ameliore_ma_maitrise_du_francais/fiches-outils/accents_e/co/groupes_consonnes_1.html

"Lorsqu'il y a une suite de consonnes entre deux voyelles :

- si ces consonnes constituent un groupe consonantique d'attaque de milieu de mot, elles servent d'attaque à la seconde syllabe ;

- sinon, elles se répartissent entre traîne de la première syllabe et attaque de la seconde syllabe :
"

Comment: Merci pour votre effort louable pour essayer de me rendre intelligible le découpage des syllabes. A vrai dire, les règles sont assez complexes, j'ai dû bien m'accrocher pour trouver dans quel cas tombait mon exemple. Si vous me suivez, c'est *br* (de célebre) qui est un "groupe consonantique d'attaque de milieu de mot" et qui donc ne doit pas être réparti entre deux syllabes (-br donc et non b-r) contrairement à *ct* (de sélection).